# How do I check if a^b == c^d. The issue I'm facing is speed with the loops. I've already optimized the part to find the exponents

Tags: c++, loops, math, optimization

Here's the functions. Basically I loop from 1 to n and check if a^b == c^d. I was wondering if there's a faster way to do this.

```
int power(int x, int n) {
    if (n < 0)
        return this->power(1/x, -1*n);
    else if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (n == 1)
        return x;
    else if (n % 2 == 0)
        return this->power(x * x, n / 2);
    else if (n % 2 != 0)
        return x * (this->power(x * x, (n - 1)/2));
}

int count(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    n = n + 1;
    for(int a = n; a >= 1; --a) {
        for(int b = n; b >= 1; --b) {
            for(int c = n; c >= 1; --c) {
                for(int d = n; d >= 1; --d) {
                    if (this->power(a,b) == this->power(c,d))
                        count = count + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count % (this->power(10, 9) + 7);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `^` to mean exponentiation in a C++ context. In C++ `^` means XOR.

Comment: Nothing to do with performance, but the construct `return; else` makes many people cringe. Get rid of the `else`.

Comment: Also, nothing to do with performance, but `if( x ) else if( !x )` also makes people cringe; get rid of the last `if()`.

Comment: Some suggestions - Do not use power function to calculate 10^9 + 7, it is not required. Moreover, do not apply modulus operation at the end because by the time you apply modulus operation the value in 'count' might have already exceeded the max limit for 'int' and the answer you will get will be incorrect. So apply modulus operation every time count is incremented or every time its value becomes greater than 10^9 + 7.

Comment: @MikeNakis: That's subjective. I for one prefer it as it is. Please do not paint your personal coding style as some sort of general moral imperative.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition sure it is subjective.  Just as toilet paper roll flowing back vs. front is subjective.

Comment: There's something fundamentally broken with this whole thing `1/x`, with `x` being an `int`, will always be 0 for any value of `x` greater than 1. That, clearly, is not the intent here.

Comment: There is probably a solution that does not involve 4 nested loops.  I assume this comes from some competition, since "return answer mod 1000000007" is a common way of design problems with DP solutions that involve integer overflows otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why recursively and repeatedly compute powers over and over again in nested loops when you can calculate them once and use them forever? (Well, for the rest of the function.)

The way you recursively calculate each power of `a` and `c` was doing the same work over and over again. I've improved the function so it computes all the possible results for the value `n` and caches them in a `vector` of `vector`s (a makeshift matrix):

```
unsigned long long count(unsigned n) {
    // Indexed as results[a-1][b-1]
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned long long>> results;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        results.emplace_back(n); // Emplace a vector with n slots
    }

    // Calcuate all the possible results for a^b, 1<=a<=n and 1<=b<=n

    // 1^n is always 1
    for (std::size_t b = 1; b <= n; ++b) {
        results[0][b-1] = 1;
    }

    // Manually calculate the rest
    for (std::size_t a = 2; a <= n; ++a) {
        unsigned long long value = 1; 
        for (std::size_t b = 1; b <= n; ++b) {
            value *= a;
            results[a-1][b-1] = value;
        }
    }

    // Compare all the things

    unsigned long long count = 0;

    // I'd change this because 1^m == 1^n for any values of m and n,
    // but I didn't make up the problem
    for (std::size_t a = 1; a <= n; ++a) {
        for (std::size_t b = 1; b <= n; ++b) {
            for (std::size_t c = 1; c <= n; ++c) {
                for (std::size_t d = 1; d <= n; ++d) {
                    if (results[a-1][b-1] == results[c-1][d-1]) {
                        // std::cout << a << "^" << b << " = " << c << "^" << d << "\n";
                        ++count;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

There are a few potential issues with this problem, however:

- 15 is the highest number for `n` you can pass, as 16<sup>16</sup> is larger than the minimum max value for `unsigned long long` (2<sup>64</sup> - 1).
- This counts cases like (1<sup>m</sup> = 1<sup>n</sup>), which is always true and doesn't need a computer to verify.
- This also counts cases that could be considered duplicates. (2<sup>4</sup> = 4<sup>2</sup>) and (4<sup>2</sup> = 2<sup>4</sup>) are counted as two cases.
- This also counts cases where (a = c) and (b = d), meaning it looks exactly the same on the left and right part of the expression (of *course* 2<sup>4</sup> = 2<sup>4</sup>)

If you want to do any higher precision than 64 bits, then you'll likely need to find a arbitrary-precision mathematics library.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a,b,c,d are positive integers (if one of them is 0, the problem is trivial):

Factorize `a` and `c`.

If one contains a prime another doesn't, a<sup>b</sup>!=c<sup>d</sup>.

Otherwise, the degrees of all primes should relate as d:b